# Bombelli's Problem

Tags: complex-numbers, math-history, cubics

So one day Bombelli was trying to solve $$x^3=15x+4$$ then he got $$x=\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt{-121}}+\sqrt[3]{2-\sqrt{-121}}.$$
How did he know that $\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt{-121}}=2+\sqrt{-1}$ and $\sqrt[3]{2-\sqrt{-121}}=2-\sqrt{-1}$?
So that $x=4$?

I have tried using $(a+ib)^3=2+1i$ then $a^3-3ab^2=2$ and $b^3-3a^2b=11$.

But it seems that you need to guess the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that Bombelli, instead of trying to *solve* the equation $x^3=15x+4$, actually *created* it, knowing from the start that $4$ is a solution. And, *if* there is a number $a+b\sqrt{-1}$, with $a,b\in\Bbb Z$ such that$$\left(a+b\sqrt{-1}\right)^3=2+\sqrt{-121}=2+11\sqrt{-1}$$then $a^3-3ab^2=2$ and $3a^2b-b^3=11$. But note that$$a^3-3ab^2=2\iff a(a^2-3b^2)=2$$and, since we are searching for integers, there aren't as many choices as that…

Comment: Bombelli _did_ in fact construct his example cubic equations around a chosen real root, since he would have had no guidance otherwise (in the mid 16th-Century) as to how to interpret the strange hybrid numbers Cardano's method produced.  It was his _knowing_ that one of those numbers was supposed to represent an integer that led him to believe that (what we would eventually call) complex numbers could have meaningful interpretations.  (He even recognized that one could do arithmetic with them.)

Answer (score 1):

When a polynomial equation with integer coefficients arises in your research, e.g.,
$$x^3-15x-4=0\ ,$$
then you "naturally" check whether it has integer solutions. In the case at hand the constant $4$ indicates that such solutions would be from the set
$$\{-4,-2, -1,1,2,4\}\ .$$
It is easily seen that $\pm1$ and $\pm2$ cannot come up with the large $15$, so that only $-4$ and $4$ have to be tried.